# Understanding embedded anonymous functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, anonymous-function

I'm trying to establish the best way to understand a series of embedded anonymous expressions such as:

```
(\f -> (\g -> (\x -> f (g x) ) ) )
```

In Haskell. I don't have too much trouble with simpler expressions such as:

```
(\x -> x + 1)
```

Which states that the function takes a Number and returns a number: 
    `Num a => a -> a`

But when things are embedded like this I get quite lost. My attempt to understand it is that the anonymous function pipes the argument from `f` to `g` to `x` right away, where I should then begin writing the typing as it is where the variable is used. But I've tried rationalizing maybe four or five different explanations and I keep getting caught up on what looks like a recursive function call in the innermost function.

Can the typing of this problem be figured out in an easier manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an example of currying. Haskell provides syntactic sugar for this:

```
\f g x -> f (g x)
```

In either case, applying the function to an argument `foo1` returns the function

```
\g x -> foo1 (g x)
```

Applying this to a function `foo2` returns *another* function

```
\x -> foo1 (foo2 x)
```

which, if applied to yet *another* argument `bar` would return the value computed by `foo1 (foo2 bar)`.

---

In a language like Python, it would look like

```
compose1 = lambda f: lambda g: lambda x: f(g(x))
```

Since Python functions are not curried by default, this is a distinct
function from `compose2 = lambda f,g,h: f(g(x))`. The difference between the two
would be how you use them.

```
compose1(foo1)(foo2)(bar)
compose2(foo1, foo2, bar)
```

Written out using `def` statements, `compose1` would look something like

```
def compose1(f):
    def _1(g):
        def _2(x):
            return f(g(x))
        return _2
    return _1
```

Comment: Thank you! The `\f g x -> f (g x)` really "fixed" my perspective. I understand it now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to overthink this. `(\f -> (\g -> (\x -> f (g x) ) ) )` is just a function of an argument `f` with *some result*... which happens to be again a function, but it's in principle no different from a function whose result is a number. It's just some blackbox...

```
\f -> ██
```

Now, when you actually apply this lambda to some `f`, you get access to the blackbox. For example, I can apply it to the [`sqrt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell98-2.0.0.3/docs/Prelude.html#v:sqrt) function:

```
(\f -> ██) sqrt
  ≡ ██
  = \g -> ██₂
```

Ok, another lambda which yields some blackbox. Let's apply that one to `(^2)`

```
(\g -> ██₂) (^2)
  ≡ ██₂
  = \x -> ██₃
```

Now that blackbox isn't so dark: it's just `f (g x)`, where `f`, `g` and `x` are arguments we've already applied:

```
(\f -> (\g -> (\x -> f (g x) ) ) ) sqrt (^2)
  ≡ \x -> sqrt (x^2)
```

Of course that's just one example. Generally, that big lambda of yours takes two functions and gives you the composition of both functions. Of course this is better written as

```
\f g x -> f $ g x
```

or in fact simply [`.`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:.)

Comment: Thank you. I was not reading it quite as a function composition with two function arguments. It makes sense once I do that!

Answer (score 1):

Think of the entire lambda function as a black box. From the signature we know there are three arrows "->" separating each argument. This tells you that this black box receives 3 actual arguments: f g x. It applies f to the result of applying g to x. It's easier to understand by looking at its named function equivalences.

```
compose f g x = f (g x)
compose' f g = \x -> f (g x)
```